# tf.train.latest_checkpoint returning none when passing checkpoint path

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

When I am trying to load checkpoint after training ENet model for prediction using tf.train.latest_checkpoint(), it's returning "None" though I am passing the correct checkpoint path.

Here is my code:

```
     image_dir = './dataset/test/'
     images_list = sorted([os.path.join(image_dir, file) for file in 
     os.listdir(image_dir) if file.endswith('.png')])

     checkpoint_dir = "./checkpoint_mk"
     listi = os.listdir(checkpoint_dir)
     print(listi)
     checkpoint = tf.train.latest_checkpoint("./log/original/check")
     print(checkpoint,'--------------------------------------- 
     ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
```

It returns None.

I am passing absolute path of checkpoint as they store in some other Dir.

Here are my checkpoint folder.

[image]

EDIT ---------------

model_checkpoint_path: "model.ckpt-400"

all_model_checkpoint_paths: "model.ckpt-0"

all_model_checkpoint_paths: "model.ckpt-400"

Comment: If your script is located in `TensorFlow-ENet` folder try running `checkpoint = tf.train.latest_checkpoint("log/original/check")`, that is without `./`. Alternatively, you can try passing the argument `latest_filename` to the `tf.train.latest_checkpoin`, i.e. `tf.train.latest_checkpoint("log/original/check", "model.ckpt-400")`

Comment: @carobnodrvo tried but same result.

Comment: In that case, can you show us what does the `check` file contains?

Comment: @carobnodrvo Sure I add into the edit section.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that your folder is mounted from a server. Try downloading the content onto your drive and be careful to pass correct paths. Where is your Python script located?

Comment: @carobnodrvo I am accessing remote pc for GPU access : Here is the absolute path => "sftp://nikhil_m@172.16.1.34/home/nikhil_m/TensorFlow-ENet/log/original/checkpoint "   . Please help how should I fix it.

Comment: Is your script also at the remote PC or are you executing your script locally?

Comment: @carobnodrvo In remote server. Everything is there.

Comment: In that case you will need to open a remote session (over SSH) and start the whole calculation from there. Are you doing so?

Comment: yes I am running everything through ssh.

Comment: Can you just try: `tf.train.latest_checkpoint("/home/nikhil_m/TensorFlow-ENet/log/original")`

Comment: @carobnodrvo thanxx bro , its working. Its better if you put it as an answer and if you have time can you explain why this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tf.train.latest_checkpoint` path argument needs to be relative to your current directory (from which Python script is executed). If it is a complex structure (i.e. data set is stored in a different folder or on a HDD) you can simply use absolute path to the folder. That is why `tf.train.latest_checkpoint("/home/nikhil_m/TensorFlow-ENet/log/original")` works in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try `tf.train.latest_checkpoint(os.path.dirname('your_checkpoint_path'))`

Comment: Please elaborate on why this is an answer to the question. If it's just a comment or a debug suggestion then it really should be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @Bracken I don't have have enough reputation to comment. I had the same problem and this solution worked for me. No idea why it works, just saw it in someone's code, went back here and posted it. Sorry if the answer doesn't meet the requirements, but maybe it will help someone

Comment: No worries, you'll get enough rep before long. It's just non-answers are very likely to be deleted.